# Get statuscode from lookup CRM field using javascript

Tags: javascript, crm

Im sitting with a piece of javascript where i have to take an entity from a lookup in crm 2011 and get the statuscode of that entity.

So far ive gotten the entityname and the entity id by writing

```
function checkProvider() {
    var providerObject = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('ib_provider');
    if (providerObject != null) {
        var id = providerObject.getValue()[0].id;
        var name = providerObject.getValue()[0].entityType;
    }
}
```

The question then is, how do i use this to get the status of the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OData endpoint to get statuscode value. Recheck following articles:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx